# Reading an SQL record and all descendants

Tags: sql, tree, extract, record, descendant

What would be the most efficient way to selectively read records from a SQL table, along with all their descendants - i.e., records in other tables with different schemas but of the same database, referencing the starting table via foreign keys?

For example, the following 4 tables have a primary key called `id` and records in Table `A` are referenced from the other 3 tables via the column `x_id`, where x = B, C, or D and `x_id` is the foreign key pointing to a record of Table X with primary key `id`.

```
Table A: id
Table B: id, a_id
Table C: id, a_id, b_id
Table D: id, a_id, c_id
```

Assuming that somehow the application knows the "graph" of table foreign key dependencies and thus can enumerate all "children" of a record (i.e., all records from other tables directly referencing it via its `id`), the data can be retrieved via multiple SELECT queries. That, however, becomes very slow for large tables.

Is there any more efficient way of getting the same information?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: When you say 'very slow' you are not talking about retrieving row-by-row' are you?

Comment: If they have proper indices, you can read all four sets of data using 4 select queries, fast.

Comment: The desired output is each record of A, along with all its descendants, if any. Access is getting slow for high numbers of records.

Comment: @tinazmu Retrieval is row-by-row, yes. Table A is scanned and, for each row, the descendants are found, if any, and retrieved as associated rows.